# wave form of the diode current of a rectifier circuit and difference between the transformer and the AC source

Tags: current, transformer, ac

So I have two questions I hope you would answer it, the first one is about how would the current Id of this circuits be? I mean his waveform.

[image]

[image]

and my second question is these two circuits who are in the same picture, one with a transformer and a circuit with an alternative source. my question is the difference between the two in the representation of Kirchoff's law is to use the U2 in the transformer circuit and the Vs in the alternative source case, right??
thank you.

[image]

Comment: 1) you are correct.  2) If you assume the transformer is ideal, then your second circuit is equivalent to your first circuit (Vs = u2).

Comment: thank you @relayman357